# How to configure skype to maintain same history location when I'm using Ubuntu/Windows in the same system?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, skype

I have installed a dual OS(`Ubuntu/Windows`) in my system. If I need to see some conversation history made over `skype` when I was using windows, I need to restart my system to move to Windows and look at the same. Will I be able to have same history location '.skpye' when I using any of `ubuntu/windows` OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently storing these files in a directory. Have not found a direct way of using it both in windows and ubuntu... but these files can be used for our reference any time needed, as any editors can open these flat files...